# Can not post JSON to server in titanium appcelerator

Tags: json, titanium-alloy

Below is my specifications I am running:

> Operating System    Name                        = Mac OS X  Version
>   = 10.9.5  Architecture                = 64bit
>     Titanium CLI    CLI Version                 = 3.4.1     Titanium SDK    SDK
>   Version                 = 3.5.0.GA    Target Platform             =
>   android
>
> ```
> Ex:-> Node.js     Node.js Version             = 0.10.24   npm Version
> ```
>
> = 1.3.21

Here is my code:

```js
var url = "http://192.168.1.100/test.php";
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
swim.lib.err('' + e.error);
alert('HTTP ERR...');
};

xhr.onload = function(e) {
Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
alert('success');
};
xhr.open("POST", url);
//post/get and your URL
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
var param = {
"user" : {
"email" : "someone@email.com",
"password" : "secure"
}
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(param));
```

Comment: Do you have any exception? And please format your code properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your server expect? I just tested your code replacing the url with http://requestb.in/157oi2x1 and that seems fine, as you can see on http://requestb.in/157oi2x1?inspect:

**Headers**

```
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connect-Time: 1
User-Agent: Appcelerator Titanium/3.5.0 (iPhone Simulator/8.2; iPhone OS; en_US;)
Host: requestb.in
Total-Route-Time: 0
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Language: en-us
X-Titanium-Id: d6caf6df-6a27-49b0-ad38-1c0d64356393
X-Request-Id: 257ddc46-066d-4c1d-95d6-cf6a642dbeab
Content-Length: 58
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

**Body**

```
{"user":{"email":"someone@email.com","password":"secure"}}
```

Comment: Thanks @fokke  You alright the error from server handler .
 the correct code in server using php is 
 
  `$params = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $params = json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $params));
    echo json_encode((object) $params);`